# Get removed item's key from child_removed firebase event

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to retrieve the key of the removed child's key in Firbase's `on('child_removed')` callback function?

Comment: Instead of describing the code, include the minimal code that shows your problem in the question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [Firebase documentation for `on('child_removed'`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#child-removed):

> This event will be triggered once every time a child is removed. The DataSnapshot passed into the callback will be the old data for the child that was removed.

```
firebaseRef.on('child_removed', function(oldChildSnapshot) {
  console.log('Child '+oldChildSnapshot.key()+' was removed');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me but this did:

```
firebaseRef.on('child_removed', function(oldChildSnapshot) {
  console.log('Child '+oldChildSnapshot.key+' was removed');
});
```

Use `.key` instead of `.key()`.